# Can't convert an environment to function error when using multidplyr

Tags: r, parallel-processing, dplyr, tidyverse, multidplyr

This is an example of usage of a `multidplyr` call in my code, that I run on my institute's cluster:

```
#create data
set.seed(1)
library(dplyr)

df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:100,function(i){
  id.df <- data.frame(id=paste0("ID",i),value=runif(1000,0,5),group=c(rep("group1",500),rep("group2",500)))
  id.df$value[sample(1000,250,replace=F)] <- 0
  return(id.df)
})) %>% dplyr::group_by(id)

#simple function
tTest <- function(df)
{
  df$p.value <- t.test(dplyr::filter(df,group == "group1")$value,dplyr::filter(df,group == "group2")$value)$p.value
  return(df)
}

#call to multidplyr
df %>% multidplyr::partition(id) %>% multidplyr::cluster_library("tidyverse") %>% multidplyr::cluster_library("MASS") %>%
  multidplyr::cluster_assign_value("tTest", tTest) %>%
  do(results = tTest(.)) %>% dplyr::collect() %>% .$results %>% dplyr::bind_rows()
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
Initialising 15 core cluster.
── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.2.1 ──
✔ ggplot2 3.0.0.9000     ✔ readr   1.1.1
✔ tibble  1.4.2          ✔ purrr   0.2.5
✔ tidyr   0.8.1          ✔ stringr 1.3.1
✔ ggplot2 3.0.0.9000     ✔ forcats 0.3.0
── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()

Attaching package: ‘MASS’

The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’:

    select

Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) :
  15 nodes produced errors; first error: Can't convert an environment to function
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
In addition: Warning message:
group_indices_.grouped_df ignores extra arguments
```

And:

```
> rlang::last_error()
NULL
```

So I don't really know where to begin to debug this problem.

Anyone have an idea?

Here's the `sessionInfo` in case it's useful:

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /sw/R/R-3.4.3-install/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /sw/R/R-3.4.3-install/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
 [1] MASS_7.3-51        forcats_0.3.0      stringr_1.3.1      purrr_0.2.5
 [5] readr_1.1.1        tidyr_0.8.1        tibble_1.4.2       ggplot2_3.0.0.9000
 [9] tidyverse_1.2.1    dplyr_0.7.7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.19          cellranger_1.1.0      pillar_1.1.0
 [4] compiler_3.4.3        plyr_1.8.4            bindr_0.1.1
 [7] tools_3.4.3           jsonlite_1.5          lubridate_1.7.4
[10] gtable_0.2.0          nlme_3.1-137          lattice_0.20-34
[13] pkgconfig_2.0.2       rlang_0.2.2.9001      cli_1.0.1
[16] rstudioapi_0.7        parallel_3.4.3        haven_1.1.2
[19] bindrcpp_0.2.2        withr_2.1.2           xml2_1.2.0
[22] httr_1.3.1            hms_0.4.2             grid_3.4.3
[25] tidyselect_0.2.5      glue_1.3.0            R6_2.3.0
[28] readxl_1.1.0          multidplyr_0.0.0.9000 modelr_0.1.2
[31] magrittr_1.5          backports_1.1.2       scales_1.0.0.9000
[34] rvest_0.3.2           assertthat_0.2.0      colorspace_1.3-2
[37] stringi_1.2.4         lazyeval_0.2.1        munsell_0.5.0
[40] broom_0.5.0           crayon_1.3.4
```

Trying the same on my benchtop Mac it runs fine. 
I benchmarked this `multidplyr` call with a simple call with on my benchtop and got:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           expr
 df %>% multidplyr::partition(id) %>% multidplyr::cluster_library("tidyverse") %>%      multidplyr::cluster_library("MASS") %>% multidplyr::cluster_assign_value("tTest",      tTest) %>% do(results = tTest(.)) %>% dplyr::collect() %>%      .$results %>% dplyr::bind_rows()
      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 190.7746 195.7953 206.1758 203.7096 213.0648 296.4428   100


Unit: milliseconds
                                   expr      min      lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
 df %>% dplyr::group_by(id) %>% tTest() 16.28017 18.2625 19.45435 18.6393 19.06788 30.07284   100
```

Is there some constant overhead that `multidplyr` is adding to set up the cores, that gets measured in `microbenchmark`, which makes it seem much less favorable in this toy example, but definitely worth it in much bigger data sets?

Otherwise, am I missing the point in using `multidplyr`?

Thanks a lot